# JavaScript: Defining function inside function

Tags: javascript

In this [W3Schools example](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_create_object3), I am not getting how `changeName` works:

```
function person(firstname, lastname, age, eyecolor) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyecolor = eyecolor;

    this.changeName = changeName;

    function changeName(name) {
        this.lastname = name;
    }
}
myMother = new person("Sally", "Rally", 48, "green");
myMother.changeName("Doe");
document.write(myMother.lastname);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MrGe4/

Why do we have `this.changeName=changeName`, and then a function definition for `changeName`?

Comment: And **please** do not use w3schools...

Comment: Read this: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: One possible reason for the downvotes is that questions should avoid depending on external resources. I added the code inline for you. The question isn't very clear (probably because you are confused), and the lack of code in its body didn't help.

Comment: In JavaScript doesn't matter where you define the function, unless it's not anonymous function assign to a variable.

Comment: @Neal It doesn't make sense to downvote for asking about code found in w3schools; it's not the OP's fault that it's a bad resource. Also, what would be a valid answer to "what have you tried" in a "why" question?

Comment: @bfavaretto the 1st comment is the reason for my dv

Comment: @Neal: As bfavaretto said, what are you expecting me to try here if I am not clear with whats going on?

Comment: @bfavaretto : thanks gotcha, will take care to include code in my question. And yes, I was really confused, probably I should move away from w3schools as others are suggesting.

Comment: @Tingya Yes, you really should. Check the [JavaScript tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info) for a list of better resources.

Comment: @bfavaretto: I didn't know the links to tutorials are available on StackOverflow, and also didn't know about jsfiddle, thanks a ton for these details!

Comment: The jsfiddle was added by another user (click the "edited" timestamp to see the edit history), I just moved it below the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is defining a method `changeName` for the `person` objects - but in a sort of round-about way, the equivalent (and better) way to do it is:

```
this.changeName = function(name) {
  this.lastname = name;
}
```

(Hence 'please do not use w3school')

Comment: Not necessarily better, because now the functions is anonymous not named.

Comment: @Bergi: sorry, I don't understand the objection - why would you want/need the named function?

Comment: They help a lot in debugging and sometimes make code more readable. http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's you code (From the reference you made):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
function person(firstname,lastname,age,eyecolor)
{
this.firstname=firstname;
this.lastname=lastname;
this.age=age;
this.eyecolor=eyecolor;

this.changeName=changeName;
function changeName(name)
{
this.lastname=name;
}
}
myMother=new person("Sally","Rally",48,"green");
myMother.changeName("Doe");
document.write(myMother.lastname);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When you type this code:

```
function changeName(name)
{
this.lastname=name;
}
```

you're basically making a function.

And when you do this:

```
this.changeName=changeName;
```

you're basically saying that "the function changeName (on the RHS) belongs to **this** function, i.e. person. (However, person is being used as an object)"

Hence when you see , the code given by your link, the global code defines an object **myMother** and it accesses `changeName` via `myMother.changeName()` just because you said, `this.changeName  = changeName`

Answer (score 1):

This.changeName is a property.

this.changeName=changeName is just the declaration of the function.

```
//Here you create your Person Object
myMother=new person("Sally","Rally",48,"green");

//Here you affect the LastName "Doe" By calling the ChangeName function of the object Person
myMother.changeName("Doe");
```

Comment: The assignment of the function does not affect the `lastName` property.

Comment: it sets the lastname property to "Doe" in this case.

Comment: That's when you *call* the method. Only assigning the function (`this.changeName=changeName`) does not do this.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript this code:

```
function foo() {
    function changeName() {

    }
    this.changeName = changeName;
}
```

is the same as

```
function foo() {
    this.changeName = changeName;
    function changeName() {

    }
}
```

It's becasue of hoisting in javascript all declartions are putted at the begining by the interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

Here are additional answers to some likely questions:

JavaScript only has two scopes:

1. Global Scope
2. Function Scope

There is **no block scope** in JavaScript!

All variables declared inside a scope are available as if they were all declared at the begin of that scope, due to **variable hoisting**.

This is why it is recommended to declare all variable at the begin of their scope, to better reflect reality, possibly in a single var declaration.

e.g.

```
function person(firstname, lastname, age, eyecolor) {
    var changeName = function (name) {
        this.lastname = name;
    }
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyecolor = eyecolor;

    this.changeName = changeName;

}
```

Actually, in this case, the variable or named function is not needed at all.

Just assign an anonymous function to the object property directly:

```
function person(firstname, lastname, age, eyecolor) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyecolor = eyecolor;
    this.changeName = function (name) {
        this.lastname = name;
    }
}
```

Tools like JSLint or JSHint will help you improve your JavaScript code.

See [this sample @ codepen.io](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bEJFn) (press CTRL+SHIFT+7 in the JS Editor) and [JSHint use at codepen.io](http://blog.codepen.io/2013/06/11/inline-error-messaging-for-js-hint/).

Finally, the Mozilla Developer Network is a much better resource than W3Schools.

It will even teach you in the [document.write Notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write#Notes) that is not good practice.

Comment: Thank you for detiled explanation, +1 specially for mentioning `Javascript` has no block scope